# Windows Mobile 10 Background Task DNS Fails

Tags: uwp, windows-mobile

I am running into a problem with my background task on Windows Mobile 10 (build 10.0.14393.82).  In my background task, HTTP client is sometimes throwing an Exception with the error (note it seems to happen when the phone is locked):

The server name or address could not be resolved

The phone shouldn't have an issue resolving the address, since it resolves it fine when running in the foreground.

Has anyone else seen this issue, or have any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage this to work? I'm getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

check the IsNetworkRequested property when registering your background task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder#properties_

Comment: And this...is the answer I was looking for... going to check this right now...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you check (or does your background task scheduler check) if there is an active Internet connection before you make your DNS probe request? 
It looks like the device is turning wireless off during sleep mode.

Comment: Yep.  Before I connect I check the internet status: NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile().GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() returns NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess

Comment: @MichaelSabin Michael, could you please share a minimized demo? It's helpful to reproduce your issue?(e.g. Trigger/Condition/Frequency...)

Comment: @franklin-chen-msft  I have an example app here: https://github.com/mjsabin01/UwpExample. You can ignore what the foreground app does.  Just launch once and it will create a background task that gets bing.com.  If successful it will update the badge count...  In the FieldMedic-Networking logs I see the following error: "DNS query for www.bing.com hostname failed: Handle=0x00CC000C Error=12007"