# Http error in background task Windows 10 mobile (UWP)

Tags: background, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a background task which executes a http request, but only works a small number of times. The error returned is: "**The server name or address could not be resolved**". The url is correct and works fine if I execute it from main app.

The code is a simple http request with a "HttpClient":

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
        {
            var c = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        _deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

As I've said, the **same url** Works sometimes and sometimes not, and yes, I'm checking internet connection before each request.
Any ideas please?

**EDITED**:
Here is my phone info:
[image]

And here is the repo with a test app demonstrating the issue: https://github.com/CabuxaMapache/BackgroundTask.Test

**EDITED 2**:
I've tested the app in a Lumia 640 with the same results, over 100 executions and only 10 of them OK. Here is the L640 info:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the address you're connecting to a public one (e.g. google), or is it an address in your private network?

Comment: It's a public adress

Comment: Here is a related one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300532/windows-mobile-10-background-task-dns-fails

Comment: Have checked about other URLs if they have the same results that sometimes works and sometimes not? What's the background task trigger ? If conveniently could you please share a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, I've checked different urls with same results. The background trigger is a "TimeTrigger" setted to 15 minutes.

Comment: I will send an example link ASAP.

Comment: Here is the repo with a simple app: https://github.com/CabuxaMapache/BackgroundTask.Test

Comment: We have a testing on our side with local machine and Lumia 640, both are work well. Did you have another device for testing to confirm if it is your device issue?

Comment: I will test it in my wife´s Lumia 640 and tell you. Thank you very much for the feedback.

Comment: Tested in my Lumia 640 and same results (or even worse) than in my 930. Something is going on here and I wonder what it is...is there a problem with creators update and Windows 10 Mobile background tasks? BTW, I've edited the question with the 640 specifications. Any help will be wellcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally, the answer is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder#properties_, thanks Dave Smits!